# Correlation/request_ids are over lapped in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, rest, logging, fastapi

I want to add a correlation-id or request-id in my log messages to see the full traceability. But request IDs overlapped once I called the `/wait` API. Basically, I check the behaviour if some API take time to perform the task, what happens with other API calls.

Here is my implementation for setting logging and API routes in `main.py` file

```
import logging
import uuid

from logging import LogRecord
from fastapi import FastAPI

import common


app = FastAPI()

# Setup Logger
class ContextInfo(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, request_id: str=None):
        self._request_id = request_id

    def filter(self, record: LogRecord) -> bool:
        record.request_id = self._request_id
        return True

logger = logging.getLogger('test-app')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - request_id: %(request_id)-15s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

# On default behaviour, we don't set any request_id
# because we don't have at the very beginning
context_info = ContextInfo()
logger.addFilter(context_info)

logger.propagate = False


@app.get("/wait")
async def wait():
    ranGenReqId = str(uuid.uuid4())
    context_info = ContextInfo(request_id=ranGenReqId)
    logger.addFilter(context_info)


    logger.info("Request comes from client to get long-waited resource access")
    await common.wait_longer()

    logger.info("Request /wait completed successfully")
    return {"message": "I am come afer long wait"}


@app.get("/quick")
async def quick():
    ranGenReqId = str(uuid.uuid4())
    context_info = ContextInfo(request_id=ranGenReqId)
    logger.addFilter(context_info)

    logger.info("Request comes from client to get quick resource access")
    common.quick()

    logger.info("Request /quick completed successfully")
    return {"message": "Quick response"}
```

Every time a request comes from the client, I generate a unique request ID and add it to log message context via the `Filter` class

Now suppose I have some helper functions called from `common.py` to do some stuff

`common.py`

```
import logging
import asyncio


logger = logging.getLogger('test-app')

async def wait_longer():
    logger.info('Starting long process')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return None

def quick():
    logger.info('Starting quick process')
    return None
```

Now see request_id in log messages are overlapped with previous calls. I called `/wait` 5 times in a row.

[image]

We can clearly see logs after some new lines (Enter new lines), request id `2c5df98f-589d-49b4-9559-5321f859a6c9` appear on first four api calls which is NOT expected.

I am wondering why is this happens?
AFAIK FastAPI works asynchronously and every request handle by separate thread.

Comment: But your `logger` object is globally defined - it belongs to the worker, so you're just adding new filters to the logger of that worker - and the last one survives (all those tasks are probably handled by the same worker)

Comment: FastAPI working asynchronously means the exact opposite of each request being run in a separate thread. There is one thread woth an event loop, that switches between tasks when encountering `await`.

Comment: The functionality you're after I suspect is a [`ContextVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#context-variables), which provides a separate context for each async task. You could also use the [starlette-context package](https://github.com/tomwojcik/starlette-context), which is built exacly for this (it handles the async `ContextVar` for you).

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful as well, in order to better understand how FastAPI/Starlette works under the hood.